# What does being hyped means

Tags: meaning

I saw the word **hype** and as far as I know by now it means being excited, but im not sure with such sketchy information I found. 
I was wondering if I could use it to say

> The new Scream Queens season is premiered today: OMG i'm so hyped up!

Is it correct? I know I can use something like "I'm so thrilled" or similar but i wanna sound too complex when I post my snapchat so my friends say  "Wow, he really knows plenty of English!"

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Google search for [hyped definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=hyped+definition)

Answer (score 1):

"Hype" is derived from classical Greek meaning "over, above or beyond".  It has been adapted from words like hyper-active to mean agitated, and from hyperbole to mean over-promoted or exaggerated.  In slang usage, hyped, amped, pumped and jazzed all mean excited, so feel free to use it in that context.

"Hyped-up on drugs" is a common phrase -- a connotation you might want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

In your examples, "hype" is being used to mean "excitement".

> being hyped up - *being in a general state of excitement*
>   Why are you so *hyped up* about something so boring?
>
> hyping up - *generating excitement*
>   They are really *hyping up* the new season with so many commercials.

I've never really heard "hyped up" being used in first person, usually what could be used is

> psyched up
>   very excited
>   totally rock'in
>   definitely looking forward to

"hyped up" can be used as an observation

> He's so hyped *(up)* about...
>   Why are you so hyped *(up)* about... ?

"Thrilled" is different then "hyped up", "thrilled" usually gets used for *something* that has already happened, "hyped" is used in anticipation of *something* happening.